# Running Python launch files with arguments

Tags: python, ros2, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Greetings. Is there a way to use arguments within launch files written in Python?

I have found the possibilities offered by [roslaunch](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/arg), however I was wondering how to achieve the same effect in Python launch files.

To be more specific I want to create a number of robots for simulation purposes. For this I would like to supply a list of pose coordinates, spawning the corresponding number of robots at the respective poses.

In order to achieve this I plan to iterate in the launch file to create separate namespaces for each robot before spawning them.

Therefore, is there a way to pass some command line arguments like `ros2 launch my_sim_bringup multiple_robots.launch -x 0 -y 0 -z 0` ?

Could I define generate_launch_description like this `def generate_launch_description(my_arg)`, as I would do with any Python function to achieve this behavior?

I am very sorry for asking such basic questions, but the [documentation](https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/master/launch/doc/source/architecture.rst#id69) regarding the Python launch system is lacking.

---

EDIT: Doing further research I found: [ros2 access current LaunchConfiguration](https://answers.ros.org/question/322636/ros2-access-current-launchconfiguration/?answer=359167#post-id-359167), [Access launch argument in LaunchFile ROS2](https://answers.ros.org/question/340705/access-launch-argument-in-launchfile-ros2/) as well as [ROS2: How to pass arguments from one launch file to a child launch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57696569/ros2-how-to-pass-arguments-from-one-launch-file-to-a-child-launch-file). But to be frank, I don't get it.

Using the method proposed by these links I have implemented in my launch file:

```
ld = LaunchDescription()    
robot_positions = DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'positions',
            default_value="000",
        )
ld.add_action(robot_positions)
```

as well as

```
positions = LaunchConfiguration('positions', default="000")
```

Now I was lead to belief that it was possible to use [command line arguments or superordinate launch files](https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/d9def23d24b500c7c4b10f79297059b793b27152/launch/launch/actions/declare_launch_argument.py#L35-L37) to supply the values. Something like this for command line `ros2 launch my_sim_bringup multiple_robots.launch positions:=000`

However, `positions` does not hold the string "000", rather a LaunchConfiguration object, which as far as I can see it in [launch_configuration.py](https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/d9def23d24b500c7c4b10f79297059b793b27152/launch/launch/substitutions/launch_configuration.py) has no getter functions for retrieving the value.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372544/running-python-launch-files-with-arguments/) by [NotARobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/69326/notarobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2021-02-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) on 2021-03-11**:
Please have a look at [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/373139/ros2-how-to-pass-commandline-arguments-to-launch-files/?answer=373818#post-id-373818) answer. Maybe it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you for your answer destogl. I have to confess the solution I was looking for is very trivial and is more generic to Python.

I have solved the problem by using argv to get the desired effect.

---

Originally posted by [NotARobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/69326/notarobot/) with karma: 109 on 2021-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0